# Where can I find the template of this paper which resembles to informs journals?

Tags: templates

I am looking for the LaTeX template for this [paper](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=250070119116013118127096104112022099029051017051045044067090004120116108111112114091055102119102108111124007070029104106095120010005061051067106072097122123011095011034038018092119000123126074113117102102068091006072089001123112010079073118116027000003&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE). There are many papers in SSRN that use this template. It looks like INFORMS templates but the font of sections, color of citations, are different. Also, there is no red text on the top, submitted to "journal name", journal name on the top of each page are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INFORMS template can be slightly reconfigured to meet your needs. You can change color of citations and other links as follows:

```
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 20, 114}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=myblue,linkcolor=myblue,citecolor=myblue]{hyperref}
```

According to the INFORMS style, the following commands should be used when `hyperref` is loaded

```
\def\EMAIL#1{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}
\def\URL#1{\href{#1}{#1}}
```

To remove red text and headers add this commands to the preamble:

```
\def\theARTICLETOP{}
\def\theLRHFirstLine{}
\def\theLRHSecondLine{}
\def\theRRHFirstLine{}
\def\theRRHSecondLine{}
```

The font of sections seems to be the same as in INFORMS template. In any case you may change it as you like.

Comment: Thank you so much